# Dockerfile with node, java, and Dynamodblocal

Tags: java, node.js, docker

I am trying to create a docker file that contains the following

1. Nodejs
2. java (jre)
3. Dynamodb local

So far I was able to get the Node part done through node:argon but not sure how to get the rest done.  This is what my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM node:argon


# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install


# # Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Can someone show me how to get java (jre) and dynamodblocal on this same image.  I know ideally you should have dynamodblocal on a separate container but I think dynamodblocal can be accessed through localhost only.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you should use a separate container for dynamodblocal and then link to your application

```
docker run -d --name dynamodb deangiberson/aws-dynamodb-local

docker run -d -P --name my_node_app --link dynamodb:dynamodb nodeApp
```

In your application get the connection using `dynamodb` as hostname instead of `localhost`